# Django autocomplete fields do NOT work when using a horizontal filter on a many to many field

Tags: python, django, autocomplete, django-templates, admin

I am using django's auto complete light to make a custom form. In this model there is another field which I would like to apply a horizontal filter to. However whenever I apply the filter, the autocomplete forms do not work anymore.

```
@admin.register(model)
class modelAdmin(VersionAdmin):
   form = autoCompleteForm

   filter_horizontal = ('many_to_many_field',)
```

Open to any solutions, I have searched around and cannot seem to find any other similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who has the same problem as me. How I got around this problem was I made my own custom widget using autocomplete-light for the many to many field. This still allows to select multiple but allows for a smaller field, its the same size as a charField.

```
from dal import autocomplete

class many_to_many_field_Autocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = *custom query if needed*

        #search option
        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(name__icontains=self.q)

        return qs
```

Then add the widget to the urls.py file,

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(
        r'^model-autocomplete/$',
        many_to_many_field_Autocomplete.as_view(),
        name='model-autocomplete',
    ),
]
```

Then add the custom widget to that field inside of the form class

```
class VersionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = model_name
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'many_to_many_field_name': autocomplete.ModelSelect2Multiple(url='model-autocomplete'),
        }
```